# how to append django data to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a django view which pass two lists to html template like this:

views.py

```
sale_day = dash[0]
sale_amt = dash[1]
context_dict = {'sale_day':sale_day,
                'sale_amt':sale_amt}
return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context_dict)
```

In html template i can display data using a for loop like:

```
{% for day in sale_day %}
    {{day}}
{% endfor %}
```

But i want to pass the data to a javascript tag inside the html file.
I passed the lists like:

```
<script>

var sale_day = {{sale_day|safe}}
var sale_amt = {{sale_amt|safe}}
```

Now i want to populate a javascript array from my two lists. My array is like:

```
data = [
    { day: '1', amt: 100},
    { day: '2', amt: 75},
    ....
]
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dict in your view, dump it to JSON, and use it in the template.

```
data = data = [{'day': day, 'amt': amt} for day, amt in zip(sale_day, sale_amt)]
json_data = json.dumps(data)
return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {"data": json_data})
```

...

```
var data = {{ json_data|safe }}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{{data|safe}}` in html instead of `{{json_data|safe}}`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to serialize the Python dictionary into a JSON object. There are many ways to do this. The simplest is to use:

```
import json
json.dumps(data)
```

To serialize a Django model, take a look at: [Django documentation: Serializing Django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/)